# Javascript drag and drop on leave doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement a drag and drop image upload similar functionality to imgur.com.
You drag an image from your desktop and a big overlay div with the word 'upload' appears as you drag over your document.

My problem is that when I drag over the actual word 'upload' inside an h1 tag the screen flickers. This is happening because I have an event for dragleave to remove the overlay div with the upload h1 tag however I don't know how to fix it.

You can see the problem in action here: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JUBwS/7/), just drag any image from your desktop to the document and hover over the word 'upload' you'll see what I'm talking about. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drag and Drop</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="upload-global-drop-overlay" style="display: none;"><h1>upload</h1></div>
    </body>
</html>​
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).on('dragover', function () {
    $('#upload-global-drop-overlay').css({'display': 'block'});
});


$('#upload-global-drop-overlay').on('dragleave', function () {
    $('#upload-global-drop-overlay').css({'display': 'none'});
});

$(document).on('drop', function (e) {
    $('#upload-global-drop-overlay').css({'display': 'none'});
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

​

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey hopefully you found an answer to this, if not here is a little example that looks like imgur in my oppinion, using your code.

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/JUBwS/74/

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drag and Drop</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="upload-global-drop-overlay" style="display: none;"><h1>upload</h1></div>
    </body>
</html>​
```

**CSS**:

```
#upload-global-drop-overlay {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #424242;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
opacity: .8;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
-moz-opacity: .8;
z-index: 10001;
display: none;
}

#upload-global-drop-overlay h1 {
font-size: 72pt;
display: block;
position: absolute;
line-height: 50px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: -82px 0 0 -180px;
text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px black;
color: white;
z-index: -1;
}​
```

**Javascript**:

```
var isDragging = null;
$(document).on('dragover', function () {
    if(isDragging==null)
        doDrag();

    isDragging = true;
});

$(document).on('drop', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isDragging = false;
});

$(document).on('dragleave', function (e) {
    isDragging = false;
});

var timerId=0;
function doDrag()
{
  timerId = setInterval(function()
  {
    if(isDragging)
        $('#upload-global-drop-overlay').fadeIn(500);
    else
    {
        $('#upload-global-drop-overlay').fadeOut(500);
        isDragging = null;
        clearInterval(timerId);
    }
  },200);
}​
```

This sample uses timers, but it is active only when something is being dragged into the form. I am certainly going to use this in the future.

Comment: Hanlet Escaño - Thank You! Exactly what I wanted. You even got the fading just like imgur!

Comment: Reducing the fadeIn/Out time ends in flimmering over here. Even if you also decrease the setInterval speed it keeps flimmering. Any ideas about that? I sec fadeIn/Out to 200, the update interval to 64.

Answer (score 2):

I actually found another solution, I think it's a bit simpler because it doesn't use setInterval. And I've implemented the actual drag and drop functionality for anyone interested.

The whole working example with drag and drop functionality is available below.

**jsFiddle - Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6SV9P/1/

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drag and Drop</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="upload-global-drop-overlay" style="display: none;"><h1>upload</h1</div>
        <div id="image"></div>
    </body>
</html>​
```

**CSS**:

```
#upload-global-drop-overlay {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #424242;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: .8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    -moz-opacity: .8;
    z-index: 10001;
    display: none;
}

#upload-global-drop-overlay h1 {
    font-size: 72pt;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -82px 0 0 -180px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px black;
    color: white;
    z-index: -1;
}​
```

**JS:**

```
var dragDropFromDesktop = (function ($) {
    $(document).on('dragenter', function () {
        $('#upload-global-drop-overlay').fadeIn(200)
    });

    $('#upload-global-drop-overlay').on('dragleave', function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.pageX < 10 || e.originalEvent.pageY < 10 || $(window).width() - e.originalEvent.pageX < 10 || $(window).height - e.originalEvent.pageY < 10) {
            $("#upload-global-drop-overlay").fadeOut(200);
        }
    });

    $('#upload-global-drop-overlay').on('dragover', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Handle dropped image file - only Firefox and Google Chrome
    $('#upload-global-drop-overlay').on('drop', function (e) {
        $('#upload-global-drop-overlay').fadeOut(200);
        var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
        if (files === undefined) {
            alert('Your browser does not support file Drag and Drop!')
        } else {
            var file = files[0];
            if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined" && file.type.indexOf("image") != -1) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (evt) {
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.src = evt.target.result;
                    $('#image').html('<img src="' + img.src + '">');

                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

})(jQuery);​
```

Comment: If on firefox, drag unmaximized windows over the body area, and then drag something from ita and then drag back in window again, so the cursor will not leave the body area, overlay will not be cleared.